# How to open this "console" to install a package in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, package

look at this Video, at 3:24 he uses a hotkey to open a "console". How can I do this on Windows?

https://youtu.be/s04iBjIFTRg?t=204

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do as,

```
ctrl + shift + p
```

Comment: thanks. but when I type what he types in the video, VS tells me that it cant find anything

Comment: got it, i had to install the Pubspec Assist extension before

Comment: @SiggiSmilez You can refer https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist